# How to add a table name in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have one question about "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE".
I have dynamicly changed table name in next plsql statement

```
DECLARE

TYPE CurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
cur CurTyp;
str1 VARCHAR2(30);
str2 VARCHAR2(30);
table_name  VARCHAR2(30);

BEGIN

select data
  into table_name
  from ref
 where o_id = 111
   and a_id = 222;



OPEN cur FOR
'select  name, sname  from :1 b,myobjects a where a.obj_id = b.obj_id'
USING table_name;
LOOP
FETCH cur INTO str1, str2;
EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
dbms_output.put_line(str1||str2);
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur;
END
```

Is it possible to read the result of next *Execute Immediate* query to cursor?

```
'select  name, sname  from :1 b,myobjects a where a.obj_id = b.obj_id'
    USING table_name;
```

Or maybe is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ref_cursor
see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm

the example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE query_invoice(
       month VARCHAR2, 
       year VARCHAR2) IS
    TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
    c cur_typ;
    query_str VARCHAR2(200);
    inv_num NUMBER;
    inv_cust VARCHAR2(20);
    inv_amt NUMBER;
BEGIN
    query_str := 'SELECT num, cust, amt FROM inv_' || month ||'_'|| year 
      || ' WHERE invnum = :id';
    OPEN c FOR query_str USING inv_num;
    LOOP
        FETCH c INTO inv_num, inv_cust, inv_amt;
        EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
        -- process row here
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c;
END;
/
```

but as @jonearles said, you can't insert the table names as params

Answer (score 10):

For object names you must use concatenation, not bind variables.

From the [Dynamic SQL chapter of the PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#BJEDAHEE):

> The database uses the values of bind variables exclusively and does
>   not interpret their contents in any way.

Bind variables help with security and performance.  But they won't work with objects like tables.  If you pass in a table name then Oracle must interpret the contents, which will negate the security and performance benefits.

Comment: jonearles thanks for you answer, and thanks for this link it very usefull.