# PL/SQL execute immediate parameter with cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, execute

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ZAD_CZWARTE AS 

row_num number;
sql_stmnt varchar2(200);
cursor kursor is
select table_name from user_tables;
tab_name varchar2(200);
BEGIN

  FOR c_kur IN kursor LOOP
  tab_name := c_kur.table_name;
  --dbms_output.put_line(tab_name);
  sql_stmnt :='SELECT COUNT(*) FROM :1';
  execute immediate sql_stmnt into row_num using tab_name;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tab_name||' : '||row_num);

  END LOOP;

END zad_czwarte;
```

There`s a problem with execute immediate line. Anybody knows what`s the problem? everything seems just fine for me. The task is to output table names of the user with number of rows in them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a table name in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441064/how-to-add-a-table-name-in-execute-immediate-query)

Answer (score 4):

You can't bind physical table as bind variable. Your command must be `sql_stmnt :='SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || tab_name;` and then `execute immediate sql_stmnt into row_num;`